# Error in UseMethod("depth") : no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Error in useMethod(depth)

When I try to plot anything using ggplot2, I fail to produce a graph. The output changes, and is inconsistent, but in place of a graph, I receive a blank, white image, or axis without data, or all of the data, axis, and labels smushed into the center of the graph.

When making a scatter plot, like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) + geom_point()
```

I get the following error message:

```
# Error in UseMethod("depth") : no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

and a blank graph with labelled axes (note the range of errors above though).